# Matrix representation of linear map

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

Let $L:\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow R^3$ be the map defined by $L(x_1,x_2,x_3)=(3x_1+2x_2,-2x_1+x_3,x_2+x_3)$. Write down the matrix representing this linear map. Prove that $L$ is one to one, and that $L$ is invertible.

My attempt: The matrix is $\begin{pmatrix}3&2&0\\-2&0&1\\0&1&1\end{pmatrix}$ as it is the effect of the linear map on the standard basis vectors of $\mathbb{R}^3$. (I'm not sure if the matrix is this or the transpose though...).

The kernel is the set $(x,y,z)$ such that $M(x,y,z)=\bf{0}$, which we can calculate to be $(0,0,0)$ and so $dim(Ker f)=1$, as there is only one set of vectors satisfying the condition.

Since $ker=(0,0,0), L$ is 1-1 (how do I show this?). To show invertibility, I use the rank nullity theorem. $dim L=9, dim Ker f=1$, so $dim(im f)=8\ne 0$ and so it is invertible.

Is this more or less correct?

Comment: The matrix should be transposed, yes

Comment: No the matrix is correct, see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your matrix $M$ is correct, as it fulfils the property
$$
L(x) = M\cdot x
$$
for $x\in \mathbb{R}^3$.

If $L$ is invertible it is bijective and therefore automatically one-to-one.

However $L$ is invertible if and only if the corresponding matrix $M$ is invertible. You can simply calculate the determinant of $M$ to see that $M$ is invertible.

The determinant can be calculated as follows (using the rule of Sarrus):
$$
3\cdot 0\cdot 1 + 2 \cdot 1 \cdot 0 + 0 \cdot (-2)\cdot 1 - 0 - 3\cdot 1\cdot 1 - 2\cdot (-2)\cdot 1=1\neq 0
$$
As the determinant is nonzero, the matrix and therefore the linear map are invertible.

**Attention: Don't confuse dimension and cardinality!**
The *dimension* of the kernel is $0$ and not $1$, as there is just one element, meaning it's zero-dimensional. The *dimension* of the image of $L$ can be at most $3$ as we are in three-dimensional space and not $9$!

Thus with the rank nullity theorem have
$$
\dim (\operatorname{im} L) = \dim \mathbb{R}^3-\dim \ker f = 3- 0=3
$$
so $\dim(\operatorname{im} L) =3$ which means that $L$ is indeed invertible.

Answer (score 0):

The matrix one you got, that is, it's$$M=\begin{bmatrix}3&2&0\\-2&0&1\\0&1&1\end{bmatrix}.$$You can check that this is indeed correct, noting that$$\begin{bmatrix}3&2&0\\-2&0&1\\0&1&1\end{bmatrix}.\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\end{bmatrix}\text{ is indeed }\begin{bmatrix}3x_1+2x_2\\-2x_1+x_3\\x_2+x_3\end{bmatrix}.$$Since $\det M=1\ne0$, $L$ is invertible. So, $\ker L=\{0\}$, and therefore $\dim\ker L=0$. It follows now from the rank-nullity theorem that $\dim\operatorname{im}L=3$. Note that it makes no sense to say that $\dim L=9$.

Comment: How can the dimension of the image be 9 if we are in 3 dimensional space?

Comment: It was a typo. I've edited my answer. Thank you.

Comment: Why is the dimension of the image $3$? Suppose we have an $m\times n$ matrix - surely the dimension is $mn$?

Comment: @alejandro The image is a subspace of $\Bbb R^3$, and therefore its dimension cannot be greater than $3$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos what is the dimension of the $m\times n$ matrix in this case? Sorry I am really confused:(

Comment: What is the *meaning* of dimension of a matrix?

Comment: You can talk about the rank of a matrix and there is row or column rank you can talk about. However, row rank = column rank and this is the maximum amount of rows (or columns) that are still linearly independent. It depends on a matrix, but the rank is at most $\min\{n,m\}$, but e.g. the $n\times m$ null-matrix has rank $0$

Comment: However, if you talk about the vector space $M_{m,n}(\mathbb{R}$ of $m\times n$ matrices, its dimension is $9$

Answer (score 0):

A very useful theorem is that a linear transformation $T$ is one-to-one if and only if $ker(T)=\{0\}$. I'll provide a proof for you.

Let $T: V\to W$ be a linear transformation.
Suppose $T$ is one-to-one.

Let $x\in \textrm{ker}(T)$. Then $T(x)=0$.

Since $T(0)=0$, we have $x=0$ because $T$ is one-to-one. Therefore, $\textrm{ker}(T)=\{0\}$.

Suppose $\textrm{ker}(T)=\{0\}$ and let $x,y\in V$ such that $T(x)=T(y)$.

We have that $0=T(x)-T(y)=T(x-y)$. Therefore, $x-y\in\textrm{ker}(T)$ so $x-y=0$.
We can now conclude that $x=y$, implying that $T$ is one-to-one.